# How to Integrate Select2 JS in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-select2, symfony-3.4

I will show you how to integrate `Select2` in a Symfony3 project!

First, Add those 3 links to `base.html.twig` page.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Second, In `CompanyType.php` add:

```
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

 class CompanyType extends AbstractType  {
     /**
      * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
      * @param array $options
      */
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
  $builder
        ->add('country',EntityType::class, array(
                 'attr'=>array('class'=>"country",),
                 'label'=>'Country of The Head fice',                     

                  'choices_as_values' => true, //               
                 'class' => 'QSCORBundle\Entity\CountryMaps',
                 'choice_label' => 'Country_Name',
 
             ))

    ->add(...)  
}
  ...
 }
```

after that, on ur Entity file `Country.php` add:

```
public function __toString()
    {
        // TODO: Implement __toString() method.

       return $this->getCountryName();
    }
```

Finally, in your template file `xxx.html.twig` write this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".country").select2();
                });
</script>
{{ form_widget(form.country)}}
```

Here is an image of how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this by adding a data attribute to your form builder element and then having a global JavaScript file that you include to your site to take care of the select2, no need to add it to each twig file.

For example;

```
$builder
    ->add('country', 'entity', [
        'class' => 'EntityType::class',
        'label'=>'Country of The Head fice',
        'choices_as_values' => true, //               
        'class' => 'QSCORBundle\Entity\CountryMaps',
        'choice_label' => 'Country_Name',
        'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true']
]);
```

Then in a site wide js file add;

```
$('select[data-select="true"]').select2();
```

That way any select that has a data attribute of `data-select="true"` will have select2 applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer we can also create class="selectsymfony" for all select form  and in my JS i make $('selectsymfony').select2(); and in your answer you forget "]" in ('select[data-select="true"') ;)